# Iterate over a specific command line parameter

Tags: bash, variables, parameters, command-line-arguments

I have a script with multiple command line parameters and I'd like to use one of them in a for loop. Here is a simplified version:

```
while getopts s:p: flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
        s) samples=${OPTARG};;
        p) parameter=${OPTARG};;
    esac
done

for sample in $samples
do

    echo "$sample" echo "$parameter"

done
```

When I run `bash script.sh -s Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 -p test` I get:

```
Sample1 echo
```

But what I would like to get is:

```
Sample1 test
Sample2 test
Sample3 test
```

How would I go about this? I only see info for iterating through all the command line parameters using `$@` but I don't know how to iterate through a specific command line parameter. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The standard syntax for options that take an argument says that each optio tales *one* argument. Would it make more sense to make  the samples positional arguments (e.g. `bash script.sh -p test Sample1 Sample2 Sample3`), and use `"$@"` to iterate over them?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide `-s` multiple times and append the values (or use an array)

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts s:p: flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
        s) samples+="${OPTARG} ";;
        p) parameter=${OPTARG};;
        *) exit 1;;
    esac
done

for sample in $samples
do
    echo "$sample" "$parameter"

done
```

result:

```
./script.sh -s Sample1 -s Sample2 -s Sample3 -p test
Sample1 test
Sample2 test
Sample3 test
```

Comment: Solution above can be invoked using script.sh -s{Sample1,Sample2,Sample3} -ptest

Answer (score 1):

For the use case when one of the parameters is taking multiple arguments (and assuming you can modify the calling sequence) consider:

```
Script.sh -p test —- Sample1 Sample2 Sample3
```

While can be parse using modified version of your code. The advantage is that it’s easier to use with other linux tools. E.g.

```
 Script.sh -p test Sample*    # if samples are files
```

Script will be

```
parameter=defaultvalue    # default for -p, can be empty

while getopts p: flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
        p) parameter=${OPTARG};;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))  # remove options for argument list

for sample ; do

    echo "$sample" ; echo "$parameter"

done
```

Comment: This is nice, thank you. How might you add a default parameter to this? I have read that you include `p=${1:-default}` in your script but that doesn't seem to work and I am not sure where you would put it.

Comment: Answer updated for default value